# How to fix Ring Menu on Top Bar Menu got blocked by Image in Wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have problem making a ring menu on Top Bar in my own wordpress theme got blocked by Iphone Image when hovering to Ring Menu like screenshot below:
[image: ring menu problem]

**Here CSS style:**

```
.ringMenu {
  margin: -3% 0 0 31%;
  width: 0;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  /* clear: none; */
}
.navbar-default .ringMenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;


  display: block;
}

.ringMenu ul li {
  -webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  display: block;
}

.ringMenu ul li a {
  display: block;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/pOvUHA6.png?1') no-repeat scroll right/ 97% 84%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}



.ringMenu ul li.sub-ring {
  -webkit-transform: translate;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 30px;
  right: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
}
.ringMenu:hover ul .sub-ring{opacity: 1;}

.ringMenu ul li.sub-ring a{
    display: block;
  width: 110px;
  height: 115px;
}


/* top ring */

.ringMenu:hover ul li.top { 
display: block;
  top: 86px;
  left: -213px;
}

/* Bottom ring */


.ringMenu:hover ul li.bottom{
    display: block;
  top: 175px;
  left: -24px;
}

/* Right Ring */


.ringMenu:hover ul li.right {
  top: 175px;
  left: 83px;
}


/*Right2 Ring */

.ringMenu:hover ul li.right2{
  top: 146px;
  left: 185px;
}

/*Left Ring */

.ringMenu:hover ul li.left {
  top: 146px;
  left: -127px;
}

/* Left 2 Ring */

.ringMenu:hover ul li.left2 {
  top: 86px;
  left: 270px;
}
```

For further detail please check [my theme on this link.](http://dev.galerigadget.com/) So How I can fix it?

Thanks before

Answer (score 1):

Do add z-index:1 in your class ".ringMenu ul li.sub-ring" so class will be like

```
.ringMenu ul li.sub-ring {
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    left: 30px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 30px;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out 0s;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Hope so it will resolve your issue.